# NextJS: Initialize an object once

Tags: singleton, next.js

I use NextJS to generate a list of static pages.

All pages need one big static Javascript object which needs some minutes to initialize (it contains the result of parsing many other files).

```js
const bigData = initializeBigData();   // <- called for every page, instead once

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  return { bigData[params.slug] };  // ...
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to initialize this data object once. Instead the slow `initializeBigData()` runs every time when a page was created which makes the build very slow.

I've tried the following things:

- Use a module as singleton
- Use an ES6 class singleton
- Use the npm package [once](https://github.com/isaacs/once#readme)
- Reduce the build threads to 1: `npm run build --threads=1`

All these things change nothing, the long `initializeBigData()` is called for every single page when building the site.

If possible, I don't want to use a custom server.

How can an object get initialized only once in the build process of a NextJS project?

Answer (score 2):

There is a relevant discussion here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15054

But I would just use:

```js
  if (!global.font) {
    global.font = fs.readFileSync("fonts/Somefont.ttf");
  }
```

Comment: I used `globalThis` instead. like a charm